# including a std::map within a struct? Is it ok?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

```
class X_class{
public:

struct extra
{int extra1;
 int extra2;
 int extra3;
};
enum a
{
 n,m};

struct x_struct{
char b;
char c;
int d;
int e;
std::map <int, extra> myExtraMap;

};
};
```

in my code I define :

x_struct myStruct;

why do I get compile errors compiling the above class? The error either says:
1) expected ; before < on the line --- where I defined the map (above) if I eliminate std::
or
2) error:  invalid use of ::; error: expected ; before < token

Comment: it compiled, why do you say don't try?  Let me know.

Comment: @user -- Side note: I see you were trying to figure out how to properly format your code.  Just select it all and then click the { } button.  Or indent all your lines by 4 or more spaces(which is what the { } button does).

Answer (score 8):

Probably you get erorrs because you didn't `#include <map>`